# Swanwick's Dragons of Babel. Who is the girl at the end?

Tags: character-identification, the-dragons-of-babel

In the *End of the story* chapter, Will is impatiently waiting for a girl.  I really have no idea who she's supposed to be, the chapter might make more sense if there was time travel in this book, which there isn't.

This chapter happens 20 years after the end of the book.  He's been told about her by her mother.  Is she Will and Alcyone's daughter?  Is she somehow related to Esme, the young/old girl that's more important earlier in the story, but whose exact background never quite get cleared up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, the girl at the end of *The Dragons of Babel* is Will's daughter.**

This is answered by Swanwick himself in his own Q&A section called [The Squalid Answers](https://www.michaelswanwick.com/auth/squalidansw.html):

> **Lionel** writes:
>   [...] is the girl that will see's in the end his daughter?
>
> [...] the girl Will meets at the end of his novel is his daughter. No question about that at all.

Comment: Txs!  FWIW, I read the book about a month ago.  Before posting this question I had only thought about the Esme connection.  But then, as I was posting this, I thought of the possible father/daughter angle.  It made sense compared to all the puzzle pieces, but still wasn't an Aha! moment.  Wish Swanswick had been a tiny bit less cryptic.  But I guess that's his nature, esp. in this series.